# How to set a water mark in a Specific postion in FFMPEG?

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

I am Using FFMPEG With C# , And I want to add a water mark to a video , so I store the position of the user click in the media player and then Use the FFMPEG Command :

```
-i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext="Roboto-Regular.ttf":text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=300:y=100" -codec:a copy "ouput.mp4"
```

but this is not working , Any Solutions ?

Comment: You say you're using C# but there is no C# code to review to make sure you're passing the command line correctly.  If you can share that part of your code, maybe there is some syntax that needs to change.  Also, first check whether it works correctly when you run this command manually (on command line calling ffmpeg.exe) then you can narrow it down to your C# code

Comment: I am sure its working because when I set  x & y to zero the watermark appeared , but When I set x & y to other value the command not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=Roboto-Regular.ttf:text='Stack Overflow':fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=300:y=100" -codec:a copy "output.mp4"
```

Note that the double-quotes have been removed from the font file name.  In my testing this worked fine on Windows.